# Загрузить XML в DevExpress TreeView или DataGrid и считать значение узла

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, devexpress

Получаю от API примерно такой XML:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<data>
    <code>1</code>
    <descr>Успешно</descr>
    <smsid>cg8pcn3ztl5kve5ma7rcwbsv68mxbzv</smsid>
    <datetime>2018-10-01 17:20:48</datetime>
    <action>send</action>
    <allRecivers>1</allRecivers>
    <colSendAbonent>1</colSendAbonent>
    <colNonSendAbonent>0</colNonSendAbonent>
    <priceOfSending>2.09</priceOfSending>
    <colsmsOfSending>1</colsmsOfSending>
</data>
```

Можно ли загрузить этот XML в DevExpress `TreeView` или `DataGrid`? И как считать узел `code` и получить результат (значение 1)?

Comment: 1. Не уверен. Возможно, стоит изучить справку по данным компонентам. 2. Я предложил бы использовать парсинг.

Comment: Спасибо, что правите) Но может кто-то даст ответ на 1 вопрос?)

Comment: @LaNC1LoT Те, кто правят Ваш вопрос не обязательно знакомы с Delphi и не могут дать квалифициированный ответ. Но правки повышают качество вопроса, тем самым увеличивая вероятность скорейшего ответа. Сейчас  малоактивное время, многие закончили работу и едут домой. Наберитесь терпения.

Comment: MSXML + XPath пробовали?

Comment: Это еще что за чудо? 2. Вопрос уже решил, помогите с первым)

Comment: К примеру, можно почитать [вот эту статейку](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/delphi/stat/Using-XML/) и глянуть вот этот [вопросик](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383919/xpath-and-txmldocument)